# Select ListboxItem over Index(Highlight as i would click on it)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

About my Project: I want to Highlight over a Search function ListboxItems trough their Index.

Current Stage:

```
private void Menu_Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    search_person= Interaction.InputBox("Search by Name","Search...","Input Name");
    int index;
    foreach (person f in personlist) // it is an Observable Collection which works perfectly fine for me                                                                                                                               {

        if (f.name == search_person)
        {
            index = listbox.Items.IndexOf(f);
            // Here code to Highlight the (maybe) multiple objects inside the Listbox
            InfoPanel.Text += index.ToString(); // this i used to test if i get all index integers for persons inside my personlist (which seems to work perfectly fine)
        }
    }
}
```

The listbox itself is created over WPF XAML and has a Databinding to the Observable Collection which contains objects of class person.
is there a nice and proper way to highlight (like select) the Listboxitems I found over my search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with `Binding`, `DataTrigger` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation (the power of WPF widely used in [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) programming pattern).

I'll use MVVM approach for the example of what you asking for.

**Example features**

- User may type any text in `TextBox` and press `Search` button, all items containing search text will be highlighted with yellow background.

### Step 0: Helpers

The following class needed to notifying UI about change in Property. I'll derive from in other classes and simply call `OnPropertyChanged()` in property setters.

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In MVVM developers aren't using `Click` Event because there's more powerful `Command` exists. Next class implements `ICommand` interface (grabbed from the documentation page linked above). It needed for easy commands implementation in the main code.

**RelayCommand.cs**

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

### Step 1: Data

**Person.cs**

```csharp
public class Person : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _highlighted;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Highlighted
    {
        get => _highlighted;
        set
        {
            _highlighted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 2: View Model

*View Model* in **MVVM** is class where *View* (UI/XAML) may set its `DataContext` which required for `Binding`.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
    private ICommand _searchCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // It's C# 8.0 but for earlier versions of C# use the following:
    //                               _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new ...
    public ICommand SearchCommand => _searchCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is string searchText)
        {
            foreach(Person person in Persons)
            {
                person.Highlighted = searchText.Length > 0 && person.Name.Contains(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);    
            }
        }
    });
    // }));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // example data
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "Alex" },
            new Person { Name = "Jane" },
            new Person { Name = "Nick" },
            new Person { Name = "John" },
            new Person { Name = "Brett" },
            new Person { Name = "Peter" },
            new Person { Name = "Mike" },
            new Person { Name = "George" },
            new Person { Name = "Anthony" }
        };
    }
}
```

### Step 3: View

I'm providing the full markup to make everything clear. Here's `DataContext` setup and all the Controls.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" Width="300" Margin="5"/>
            <Button Content="Search" Margin="5" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=SearchTextBox}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

That's it.

[image: search and highlight]

*P.S. Code-behind class :)*

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

### Updated

In case i was wrong with understanding the question and you need an automatic selection instead of highlight, the code may be changed in the following way:

**Person.cs**

```csharp
public class Person : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _selected;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public ICommand SearchCommand => _searchCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is string searchText)
    {
        foreach(Person person in Persons)
        {
            person.Selected = searchText.Length > 0 && person.Name.Contains(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);    
        }
    }
});
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<ListBox Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: search and highlight 2]

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer which btw solved my problem.