# WPF: Change ListBoxItem Background property for MouseOver programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseover, listboxitem

My app creates a `ListBox` with c# code. I have managed to to set the background of my ListBox [white]. And managed to set some style attributes to the `ListBoxItem` (`BackgroundProperty` & `MarginProperty`).

For the **MouseOver** I defined a `Trigger` - and managed to set the `BorderThicknessProperty` & `MarginProperty`. see this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29699/WPF-How-to-create-Styles-in-code-and-magical-Conte)

But could not change the `IsMouseOver` background `BackgroundProperty`. I have tried to do like this:

```
triggerIsMouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Purple)); // Does not work
```

[image]

I have this simple XAML:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
   <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Margin="10"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And my code is like this:

```
List<string> ItemsList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ItemsList.Add("ListBoxItem: " + i.ToString());
}

Trigger triggerIsMouseOver = new Trigger
{
    Property = ListBoxItem.IsMouseOverProperty,
    Value = true
};
            
triggerIsMouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(2)));
triggerIsMouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.MarginProperty, new Thickness(1)));

// Does not work
triggerIsMouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Purple)); 

Style styleListBoxItem = new Style
{
    TargetType = typeof(ListBoxItem),
};
styleListBoxItem.Triggers.Add(triggerIsMouseOver);
styleListBoxItem.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Orange));
styleListBoxItem.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.MarginProperty, new Thickness(2)));

ListBox listBox = new ListBox
{
    ItemsSource = ItemsList,
    ItemContainerStyle = styleListBoxItem,
    Background = Brushes.White
};
            
myStackPanel.Children.Add(listBox);
```

Comment: You need to redefine the control template. Here is explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972818/listbox-mouse-over-background-color

Comment: @KonstantinBorisov - thanks. Already seen that topic, but could not figure out how this issue should look like on **Code Behind**.

Comment: Note: Creating in WPF controls in C# is a hard way. Much easier to do it in xaml. Also all styles can be applied there natively. I suggest to learn xaml.

Comment: Btw, the menuHiglight color for background is not that property you targeting. You may also redefine MenuHighlightBrush in ListBox resources. It's pretty easy but i have no idea, how to do it in C#. Redefining ControlTemplate is not mandatory to achieve that.

Comment: @aepot - thanks. The issue here is not working with Xaml, just through code. Changing the ```ListBox``` resources can be accomplished like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/491734/9615200) but it is not such a good way like mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824277/9615200)

Comment: I know nothing that isn't working with xaml. Maybe you simply not familiar with it. But displayed on screenshot control, is job for 10 minutes, including highlight and all listed in the code behavior. I'm not against code-behind approach but WPF is not intended to build apps this way, by design. Thus, it's a hard way, and almost no one prefer it. You're almost alone with the issues appeared in develop process. If you already met unresolvable issue with single ListBox, how can you build a complex software? Yes, it's possible but remember the cost. You'll migrate to the xaml, sooner or later.

Comment: Override brush, it's ok here. Anyway, the code-behind will confuse other devs more than overriden brush :)

Comment: Consider [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62352677/12888024) to learn about what approach is popular among professionals in WPF - MVVM programming pattern.

Comment: The solution is to override the `ListBox.Template` by writing a new `ControlTemplate`. Don't use C#  to create templates. You'll get no Intellisense support, since you have to write a plain string object, which is then parsed into a `ControlTemplate` object. Note that in order to create this string you'll have to write XAML code as well. You basically would use C# to create a string that must conform to XAML without the help of Intellisense. So you only lose when using C# to accomplish your task. Overriding the default brushes would help with a `DataGrid` but not `ListBox`.

Comment: NOTE: the displayed screenshot & attached code was just a sample for focusing on this issue - _Change ListBoxItem Background property for MouseOver **programmatically**_. Great thanks for all smart knowledge you shared here.

Answer (score 1):

The style is invalid because:
The default template for the `ListboxItem` contains a built-in Ismouseover trigger, which changes the effect of the template element. Causes the Ismouseover you set to be invalid. So, you need to define a control template like this. As follows:

```
<controltemplate targettype="listboxitem">
    <Border x:Name="Bd"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ContentPresenter 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
</controltemplate>
```